# An array or size unknown with all zeros and ones find the starting with XOR function python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

We have a problem where we are finding the begining of elements like below

input_arr = [ 0, 0, 0,1,1,1,1]

here i am intrested in finding the first occurence of one through XOR funtion

```
def find_0_1_sep(self,arr):
    i=0
    result=0
    while(arr[i]!=1):
        result = 1 - result
        result=arr[i+1]^result
        if(result==1):
            print(i)
        i=i+1
```

This above function is working well for if the input is starting 0 and after it one is coming.

I have tried to chnage the code so that it will work for both if the array is starting with 1 or zero any number

arr = [ 1, 1,1,0,0,0]

Code below

```
def find_0_1_sep_genric(self,arr):
    i=0
    result=arr[i]  # initializing the first element 1 or 0
    result = 1-result  # invert the value
    while(arr[i]!=result): # traversing the array untill other element
        result = 1 - result # This step not sure ??
        result=arr[i+1]^result # xor to find the result
        if(result==1):
            print(i)
        i=i+1
```

Here i am using the first element to find the number

> result=arr[i]

But it is not workin for both cases . Please help me in this regard

Comment: Why do you want to use XOR? It seems pointless.

Comment: There is no harm in using it

Comment: good to use xor in case if you want to seperate even odd

Comment: There may be some clever way to do this, but I think it won't work.  The only way is to walk down the array looking for the first 1.

Comment: we do not  know the size of array otherwise it is easy

Comment: What's wrong with `arr.index(1)`?

Comment: No harm except for extra, unnecessary code complexity, more difficult maintenance, and reduced speed.

Comment: @mypetlion what ? not able to understand

Comment: @tanuvarshney arr.index(1) will give you the index of first occurence of 1 as you seem to be looking for in your code.  Is there something else you want your code to do?

Comment: we are using it for some reason as we want the use of function further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code works when the array starts with a `0` but not a `1`, you can simply check for this explicitly:

```
if arr[0] == 1:
    # The first element is a 1, set output accordingly
else:
    # Your original code here
```

If you do not insist on the use of XOR, I suggest to solve the whole problem using a generator expression with an explicit call to `next`, like so:

```
index = next(i for i, el in enumerate(input_arr) if el == 1)
```

You can also use the builtin `index` method on `list`s (and `tuple`s):

```
index = input_arr.index(1)
```

Comment: do not confused with the element to be initialized we are struggling with the case where the array starts with 1 and it is not working in that case . if array starts with zero it is working fine .